# async/await throwing error in es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Async/ Await throwing error while compilation. Im currently using babel with presets - es2015, & plugin - transform-async-to-generator. Check my code below

```
async function verifyUserAlreadyExists(phone, email) {
    try {   
        db.collection("users").find({
        $or:{"contact_details.phone": phone, "contact_details.email": email}
        }, (err, cursor)=>{
                await cursor.count() >= 1;
        });
    }catch(err) {
        console.log("Verify User Exists:"+JSON.stringify(err));
    }
 }

export default {
    getAllUsers: (request, reply) => {
        db.collection("users").find({}).toArray((err, users) => {
            reply(users);
        });  
    },
    insertNewUser: (request,reply) => {
        let userAlreadyExists = await verifyUserAlreadyExists("7259769413");
        console.log(userAlreadyExists);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can only use `await` inside `async` functions.

Comment: So as that is a callback, how to make it async ?

Comment: Fixing the syntax error is easy (`async (err, cursor) => {...}`). The question is whether a) `.find()` returns a promise and b) `.find()` can deal with async callbacks. So, how exactly does the `.find` method work? You cannot just insert an `await` somewhere or using an `async` function. Code that is supposed to call the `async` function needs to be able to handle async functions. Do you even need an `await` there? What does `cursor.count()` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the MongoDB driver returns promises for all async functions, you <s>can</s> should rewrite your code so it doesn't use callbacks at all:

```
async function verifyUserAlreadyExists(phone, email) {
  try {
    let cursor = db.collection("users").find({
      $or : {
        "contact_details.phone" : phone,
        "contact_details.email" : email
      }
    });
    return await cursor.count() >= 1;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Verify User Exists:"+JSON.stringify(err));
    return false;
  }
}

export default {
  getAllUsers: async (request, reply) => {
    return await db.collection("users").find({}).toArray();
  },
  insertNewUser: async (request,reply) => {
    let userAlreadyExists = await verifyUserAlreadyExists("7259769413");
    console.log(userAlreadyExists);
    return userAlreadyExists;
  }
}
```

Comment: s/can/should/ :-D

Comment: Thank you so much. But i'm getting ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined. Is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Wait, don't you need to use `let cursor = await …` if `find()` returns a promise?

Comment: @manju4ever that has to do with your Babel setup. I use `es2017` for async/await.

Comment: @Bergi no, `find()` returns a cursor, not a promise. It's `cursor.count()` that does the actual async work (and returns a promise).

Comment: @robertklep  - So i had to require("babel-polyfill") in my entry.js file, that fixed the issue

Comment: @manju4ever I think that `es2017` includes that automatically (I remember having to use it some time ago, but lately I haven't needed it).

Comment: @robertklep Ah, I see, however I wonder why `find` also takes a callback if the cursor is always available synchronously anyway.

Comment: @robkertklep - So when i just use es2017 as a preset, the babel throw "import" is not a keyword, so I'm using es2015 as the preset, along with the plugin transform-async-to-generator.Am i doing it the right way ?

Comment: @robertklep thats a soothing answer :). Thanks again.

Comment: @Bergi AFAIK, `find()` doesn't take callbacks. Perhaps you're thinking of Mongoose (where it does)?

Comment: @robertklep Maybe (tbh I could never tell them apart). But in the OPs code, it does, so he seems to be using mongoose?

Comment: @Bergi I don't see any telltale signs of Mongoose-use (stuff like `db.collection()` and cursors are abstracted away with Mongoose).